# Regex - Range out of order in character class

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a regex that allows all upper&lower case letters, digits and special characters:

> % ' ` ( ) -& . / @ * , ! © ® ™

My regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9%'`()-&./@*,!©®™\s]*$/
```

However, it returns invalid regex. Please help.

Comment: Escape the `-` after the curved brackets.

Comment: Escape the literal hyphen or put it at the start/end of the character class as `)-&` is an [invalid range](https://regex101.com/r/xvD2Vj/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the dash and the slash

```
^[A-Za-z0-9%'`()\-&.\/@*,!©®™\s]*$
```

You can test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I don't think the slash needs escaping.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley when not escaped it is interpreted as a character range connector.